# odoo POS country_id displays ID and name

Tags: xml, odoo, identifier, qweb

Hello I'd like to display only the ID of the country on the PoS customer edit/create screen. I added this field to the pos.xml file:

```
<div class='client-detail'>
     <span class='label'>Country_id</span>
     <t t-esc='partner.country_id'/>
</div>
```

I expected this to return just a number (ID of the country), but it gave the ***id,name***

for example for Antartica I didn't get ***10*** as result,but ***10,Antartica***

I also tried using '*partner.country_id.id*', but this didn't returned anything.

Any help please.

Comment: partner.country_id[0] can be used

Answer (score 1):

To get the `id` you should use `country_id.id` (`country_id` is a `many2one` field).

```
<t t-esc='partner.country_id.id'/>
```